# Django: ModelForm save() method for multiple objects for a span of dates

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to make a form to save multiple instances of a Model for a span of dates provided by a user.

I have created a ModelForm with a change - excluded date (a model attribute) and added 2 fields: date_from and date_to (for a starting and ending date). I would like the form to save as many records as needed based on the dates span.

The code below doesn't work.

#### models.py

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField()

class AdminComment(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey('Tour', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()

class EmployeeComment(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey('Tour', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()

class CompanyComment(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey('Tour', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
```

#### forms.py

```
class TourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']
    date_from = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)
    date_to = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Tour
        fields = ['company', 'employee', 'date_from', 'date_to']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data['date_from']
        end_date = self.cleaned_data['date_to']
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        count = end_date - start_date

        while start_date <= end_date:
            data = {
            'company': self.cleaned_data['company'],
            'employee': self.cleaned_data['employee'],
            'date': start_date,
            }
            single_tour = Tour.objects.create(**data)
            start_date += delta

        return single_tour

class SingleTourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']

    class Meta:
        model = Tour
        fields = '__all__'
```

#### admin.py

```
class AdminCommentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AdminComment
    max_num = 1

class EmployeeCommentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = EmployeeComment
    max_num = 1

class CompanyCommentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CompanyComment
    max_num = 1

class TourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'company', 'employee')
    ordering = ['date']
    inlines = [
        AdminCommentInline,
        CompanyCommentInline,
        EmployeeCommentInline,
    ]
    form = TourForm
```

The custom save() method above doesn't work. (The method needed to return something!)
I get an error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

As there are other related Models, the form needs a save_m2m() method. Which I have not sorted out yet :(

What should I do to make it work? I am trying to make it work using Django Admin Panel.

[Edit] I have applied code changes in regards to answers and comments.

Comment: Can you show how you use it in your `admin.py` ?

Comment: Sure, I've just added what admin.py looks like

Comment: Did you import `TourForm` in your `admin.py`

Comment: Can you try to replace `return single_tour` by `return super(TourForm, self).save(commit=False)` at the end of your save method to see if it works ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try to replace these lines :

```
single_tour = SingleTourForm(data)
single_tour.save()
```

to :

```
single_tour = Tour.objects.create(**data)
```

So you will create directly the instances of the Tour model. There's no need to use a second form.

Comment: I get exactly the same error message _'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'_

Comment: And can you see from which line in the stack trace the error occurs ?

Comment: I found that save() method I have written doesn't return anything - and that was the point. Now I need to write save_m2m() method as I get an error _'TourForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'_ As it needs to save related objects (comments, I have added them to models.py in my first post so that is clear what I am talking about)

Comment: So what's the logic here ? If you write a comment in any of the inlines of the admin form, where would it goes ? In all the `Tour` instances generated in the date range ? Or only on the last one (because it's the one you're returning from the save method)